# Leela Chess PUCT Mechanism

Tags: programming, mathematics, leela

How do we know *w_i* which is not possible to calculate using the [tree search](https://medium.com/@quasimik/monte-carlo-tree-search-applied-to-letterpress-34f41c86e238) only?

From the [lc0 slide](https://slides.com/crem/lc0#/9), *w_i* is equal to summation of subtree of *V* ? How is this equivalent to winning ?

[image: tree]

[image: UCB formula]

[image: leela formula]

Comment: Beautiful chess question! Please don't expect to post a ton of formulas and graphs about something completely unrelated to chess without even explaining its context but still expect us to understand it

Comment: @David this is perfect example of why novice users dominate this SE and attempt to close non-trivial questions

Comment: @prusswan I don't want to close this question because it's non-trivial, I want to close it because it has nothing to do with chess. There is like a million Stack Exchange sites about math, statistics, machine learning, artificial intelligence, programming and all of those nerd things, so I see no reason to have yet another one

Comment: Highly technical questions about leela might find more understanding on leela discord than here.

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be closed. However, it needs a small introduction to give some context (about leela, her general algorithm, the part where $\omega_i$ appears...) so that people can have an idea what this is all about even if they cannot answer themselves.

Answer (score 4):

As you noted, `w_i` is not calculated by the search tree. It is simply the number of wins out of the total simulations performed at that node (if this is the method used to score the node). This scoring mechanism is also known as [playout](https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lc0/wiki/Technical-Explanation-of-Leela-Chess-Zero).